# Assignment of Sage Matrix to variable in R

Tags: python, r, sage

From sage (v5.4.1) in a terminal session i try to assign a value in R:

```
sage: r.assign('"M"',5)
[1] 5
```

That works. I could also do

```
sage: b=4
sage: r.assign('"M"',b)
[1] 4
```

But I would like to assign M a matrix from sage.

```
sage: r.assign('M',sage_M)
Error: object 'sage6' not found
```

The type of error depends on whether M was previously defined in R. If not, the error is as shown, otherwise unpredictable. The Matrix I want to design is of size 5x17 and of type:

```
sage: type(sage_M)
<type 'sage.matrix.matrix_integer_dense.Matrix_integer_dense'>
```

Anyone has an idea if there's a way into this?

Comment: This is a good question.  Is the solution you found (the canonical one, for now) acceptable to you or would it be worth trying to go the other way more conveniently?  We have basic conversion of R types to Sage but not as much the other way.

Comment: It works well for me as described below. Flat lists seem to be easily accepted by R. Therefore, if one is able to reconstruct the element form a flat list (trivial for matricies), the solution is fine. Oh, by the way, it might be "byrows=TRUE" for matricies depending on how it was flattened in sage.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it works by providing the matrix flattened to a list and than putting it into a Matrix again within R.